# Craft 3: admin is showing "500 Internal Server Error" (apache) after fresh install

Tags: craft3, error, admin, install

Just successfully installed a fresh copy of Craft CMS via web browser method under:
http://kultursprung.org

Frontend is visible but the admin is showing raw Apache error 500 after fresh install:
http://kultursprung.org/admin

The 500 error is not the styled Craft dev one but instead the raw Apache version.

Server requirements check passed:
http://kultursprung.org/server/checkit.php

Did set all correct file and folder permissions.

Database is showing all necessary tables as expected after a successful fresh install.

phperrors.log:

[image: phperrors.log]

UPDATE:

When I access the admin via this URL:
http://kultursprung.org/index.php?p=admin
i can provide an additional Craft styled error:
[image]

Any help?

Comment: did a fresh install with composer and now all works fine … thank you!

Comment: Your solution has been my default action when moving, updating, etc CraftCMS. I kill composer.lock and the vendor folder then run composer update. Because you're not repo'ing the vendor folder (at least you shouldn't be), it's not going to cause any conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

> (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/imagick.so.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied))

Does that file exist on your server?  I'm asking because the `.so.so` extension seems odd.  If it does and it's just `.so`, it might be as simple as editing your php.ini file so it's loading `imagick.so` instead of `imagick.so.so`.

If you php.ini file is already loading `imagick.so` and that file exists on your server at that location, then check the permissions of that file and make sure that whatever user:group your web server is running as has permissions to read that file.

Comment: Thank you Ben … all problems i described above were fixed with adding "RewriteBase /" (without the question marks) to the default .htaccess file which came with craft … there is however a new error now: after getting the login screen in admin and entering the correct login credentials i now get: Twig Syntax Error – Twig_Error_Syntax
Unknown argument "namespace" for function "svg(svg, sanitize)".
1. in /kunden/tannerhof.de/kultursprung/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/templates/_layouts/cp.html

Comment: there is however a new error now: after getting the login screen in admin and entering the correct login credentials i now get: Twig Syntax Error – Twig_Error_Syntax Unknown argument "namespace" for function "svg(svg, sanitize)". 1. in /kunden/tannerhof.de/kultursprung/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/templates/_layouts/cp.html – at line 86

Comment: did a fresh install with composer and now all works fine … thank you!